# How do I get more than the default attributes from the Microsoft Graph API when requesting all users?

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get all users from one AAD tenant with a specified schema extension.
However, when doing this request:

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(new AuthProv(_authHelper.GetAuthenticationResult().Result));

```
  var userList = new List<User>();
  var users = await client.Users.Request().GetAsync();


  userList.AddRange(users.CurrentPage);
  while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
  {
    var nextPage = users.NextPageRequest.RequestUrl;
    Debug.WriteLine("Call To: " + users.NextPageRequest.RequestUrl);
    users = users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result;
    userList.AddRange(users);
  }
```

I am receiving a JSON object that looks like:

[{"businessPhones":[],"displayName":"some account name","userPrincipalName":"somemail@email.com","id":"123","givenName":null,"jobTitle":null,"mail":null,"mobilePhone":null,"officeLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"surname":null}, ...]

However, I have customized an own attribute for users so I can retrieve values from that, but that attribute is not sent with the API response.

How can I change the request so that all user attributes are retrieved as a reponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you were using open extensions. If yes, we need to expand the **extensions** explicitly.

Here is the code to print the value of open extensions for your reference:

```
foreach (var user in users.CurrentPage)
{
    if (user.Extensions != null&& user.Extensions.CurrentPage!=null)
    {
        var customProperty = user.Extensions.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault(ext => ext.Id == "Com.Contoso.Deal");
        if (customProperty != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.UserPrincipalName}--{customProperty.Id}:{customProperty.AdditionalData["companyName"]}");
    }
}

while (users.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    var nextPage = users.NextPageRequest.RequestUrl;
    users = users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync().Result;
    foreach (var user in users.CurrentPage)
    {
        var customProperty = user.Extensions.CurrentPage.First(ext => ext.Id == "Com.Contoso.Deal");
        if (customProperty != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"{user.UserPrincipalName}--{customProperty.Id}:{customProperty.AdditionalData["companyName"]}");

    }
}
```

If there are multiple pages of open extension, you also should retrieve it via the **NextPageRequest**. Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use this new baseUrl: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/"

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/",new AuthProv(_authHelper.GetAuthenticationResult().Result),null);